# Bot not working on IRC, written in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to create a bot for an IRC server. The IRC server is: "open.ircnet.net" and the channel is "#Mal1t1a". The code of the bot is written in Node.js. I watched a tutorial on youtube about how to write the code of the bot, the video I have watched can be found at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuYIlea4j7g&t=333s . The person who did that video made a bot for twitch, so an oauth was needed. As I have connected on an IRC server, which doesn't require any password for login, I commented those lines, which contained code about the password. I am connected on the server with one of my firends, on the channel I've mentioned, and we are able to talk, so the server is working. Here, you have the code of the bot:

```
var irc = require("irc");
var config = {
    channels: ["#Mal1t1a"],
    server: "open.ircnet.net",
    botName: "tren",
    //oauth: "oauth:YOURUNIQUEOAUTHTOKEN",
    autoRejoin: false,
    autoConnect: true,
    floodProtection: true,
    floodProtectionDelay: 3000
};

var bot = new irc.Client(config.server, config.botName, {
    channels: config.channels,
    //password: config.oauth
});

function OnMessage(from, channel, text, message)
{
    console.log(from, channel, text);
    if (text == "!greeting")
    {
        bot.send("PRIVMSG", channel, "Hello " + from + "! You have triggered my command!");
    }
}
bot.addListener("message", OnMessage);
bot.addListener("action", OnMessage);

function OnJoin(channel, nick, msgobj)
{
    if (nick.toLowerCase() == config.botName.toLowerCase())
    {
        console.log("Bot has joined channel", channel);
    }
}
bot.addListener("join", OnJoin);

function OnError(message)
{
    console.log("IRC Error:", message);
}
bot.addListener("error", OnError);
```

I've written in the chat "!greeting" countless times, but the bot doesn't answer. What could it be done?

Comment: Does `console.log(from, channel, text);` log anything to the console?

Comment: no, it doesn't @Hans